# jqGrid - Custom serialization in search form (similar to serializeEditData for add/edit)?

Tags: jqgrid

I need to add custom data to the post parameters when I click the find button in the search form. If it was edit or add, I could have used the serializeEditData member. I can't find such a thing for the search.

Is there a way?

Thanks
Vivek Ragunathan

Comment: Everything is possible, but the way depends on how you use jqGrid. For example you can use saeching parameters in absolutely free form in case of usage searching implemented *on the server side*, but you have to follow standard jqGrid form in case of usage *local* data searching. So it's really required more information about **how you use** jqGrid. An example of "custom serialization" could clear many additional questions too.

Comment: @Oleg I need to take control of the serialization just as in done with Add/Edit in serializeEditData, and massage the postData by removing some parameters and adding custom parameters to the postData and have the massaged postData posted with the search url. I am looking for an extension point like serializeEditData but for search. It seems that search doesn't offer many such extension points. I could not also find an afterSubmit for search.